# intersection beween 2 files (values in file 1 which fall in range of values in file 2)

Tags: text-processing, python, perl, bioinformatics

I have a file named `snp_data` containing [SNP (Single-Nucleotide Polymorphism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) chromosome data. This is a 3-column, white-space delimited CSV file which has the following format:

```
user@host:~$ cat snp_data

snp_id    chromosome  position
Chr01__912 1 912 1
Chr01__944 1 944 1
Chr01__1107 1 1107 1
Chr01__1118 1 1118 1
Chr01__1146 1 1146 1
Chr01__1160 1 1160 1
...
...
...
Chr17__214708367 17 214708367
Chr17__214708424 17 214708424
Chr17__214708451 17 214708451
Chr17__214708484 17 214708484
Chr17__214708508 17 214708508
```

Note that for each row the `snp_id` field has the form `Chr{chromosome}__{position}` for the corresponding values of `chromosome` and `position`.

I have another file named `window` containing auxiliary data. This is a 5-column, white-space delimited CSV file which has the following format:

```
user@host:~$ cat window

seqname chromosome start end width
1 Chr1 1 15000 15000
2 Chr1 15001 30000 15000 
3 Chr1 30001 45000 15000
4 Chr1 45001 60000 15000 
5 Chr1 60001 75000 15000 
6 Chr1 75001 90000 15000 
...
...
...
199954 Chr17 214620001 214635000 15000
199955 Chr17 214635001 214650000 15000
199956 Chr17 214650001 214665000 15000
199957 Chr17 214665001 214680000 15000
199958 Chr17 214680001 214695000 15000
199959 Chr17 214695001 214708580 13580
```

Note the correspondence between the `window` and `snp_data` files determined by the value of the `chromosome` field in the `window` file and the values of the `chromosome` and `snp_id` fields in the `snp_data` file, e.g. rows with a value of `"Chr1"` in `window` correspond to rows in `snp_data` with a value of `1` for `chromosome` and whose `snp_id` rows begin with a prefix of `Chr01__`.

For each row in the `snp_data` file (each snp within each chromosome), if that row's `position` value falls within the range given by the `start` and `end` values of any of the rows in `window` for that particular chromosome, then append the `seqname` from the `window` file to the row from the `snp_data` file.

For the input given above, this would be my desired output:

```
user@host:~$ cat desired_output

snp_id  chromosome  position   window
Chr01__912  1   912      1
Chr01__944  1   944      1
Chr01__1107 1   1107     1
...
...
...
Chr17__214708367 17 214708367   199959
Chr17__214708424 17 214708424   199959
Chr17__214708451 17 214708451   199959
Chr17__214708484 17 214708484   199959
Chr17__214708508 17 214708508   199959
```

The main point is that positions are unique only within each chromosome, so I need to compare these 2 files chromosome by chromosome (i.e.. for each chromosome separately). How can I do this?

Comment: Can we assume, the width always the same - 15000? If, yes, then we don't need the `window` file at all. We can do something like this: `awk '{print $0, int($3 / 15000 + 1)}' snp_data` and get the right result.

Comment: I originally misinterpreted your question. I just updated my solution and also rewrote the question to make it clearer and address some ambiguities. Please double-check the question statement to make sure that I haven't misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @Anna1364 I updated the solution to remove the double quotes.

Comment: @Anna1364 is the "position" in snp_data actually *two* numbers "912 1" for initial rows, and only 1 number for the last rows?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python script that should do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""intersect_snp.py"""

import sys

# Read data from the SNP file into a list
snp_list = []
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as snp_file:
    for line in snp_file:
        snp_row = line.split() 
        snp_list.append(snp_row)

# Read data from the "window" file into a dictionary of lists
win_dict = {} 
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as win_file:
    for line in win_file:
        seqnames, chromosome, start, end, width = win_row = line.split()
        if chromosome not in win_dict:
            win_dict[chromosome] = []
        win_dict[chromosome].append(win_row)

# Compare data and compute results
results = []

# Iterate over snp data rows
for snp_row in snp_list:

    # Extract the field values for each snp row
    snp_id, chromosome, position = snp_row

    # Convert the chromosome to match the format in the "window" file
    # i.e. `1` -> `Chr1`
    chromosome_name = "Chr{}".format(chromosome)

    # Iterate over the "window" rows corresponding to that chromosome
    for win_row in win_dict.get(chromosome_name, []):

        # Extract the field values for each "window" row
        seqnames, chromosome, start, end, width = win_row

        # Perform the desired comparison
        if int(start) <= int(position) <= int(end):

            # If the comparison returns true, construct the result row
            result = [snp_id, chromosome, position, seqnames]
            results.append(result)
            break

# Print the output column headers
columns = ["snp_id", "chromosome", "position", "window"]
print(" ".join(columns))

# Print the results
for row in results:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Notice that this script assumes that all of your rows are data rows. If your input files are named `snp_data` and `window` then you might execute it like this:

```bsh
python intersect_snp.py snp_data window
```

If your files have header rows then you might use `tail` to skip/remove the headers and execute it like this instead:

```bsh
python intersect_snp.py <(tail -n+2 snp_data) <(tail -n+2 window)
```

Suppose that this is your `snp_data` file:

```
snp_id              chromosome  position
Chr01__912          1           912
Chr01__944          1           944
Chr01__1107         1           1107
...
...
...
Chr17__214708367    17          214708367
Chr17__214708424    17          214708424
Chr17__214708451    17          214708451
Chr17__214708484    17          214708484
Chr17__214708508    17          214708508
```

And that this is your `window` file:

```
seqnames    chromosome  start       end         width
1           Chr1        1           15000       15000
2           Chr1        15001       30000       15000
3           Chr1        30001       45000       15000
4           Chr1        45001       60000       15000
5           Chr1        60001       75000       15000
...
...
...
199954      Chr17       214620001   214635000   15000
199955      Chr17       214635001   214650000   15000
199956      Chr17       214650001   214665000   15000
199957      Chr17       214665001   214680000   15000
199958      Chr17       214680001   214695000   15000
199959      Chr17       214695001   214708580   13580
```

Then if we run this command:

```bsh
python intersect_snp.py <(tail -n+2 snp_data) <(tail -n+2 window)
```

We get the following output:

```
snp_id chromosome position window
Chr01__912 Chr1 912 1
Chr01__944 Chr1 944 1
Chr01__1107 Chr1 1107 1
...
...
...
Chr17__214708367 Chr17 214708367 199959
Chr17__214708424 Chr17 214708424 199959
Chr17__214708451 Chr17 214708451 199959
Chr17__214708484 Chr17 214708484 199959
Chr17__214708508 Chr17 214708508 199959
```

Comment: very good, +1. `int(start) <= int(position) and int(position) <= int(end)` is idiomatically  `int(start) <= int(position) <= int(end)`

Comment: @iruvar Thank you for the feedback - updated.

Comment: @igal, thanks so much. I tried your python code with a small subset of data which works perfectly fine. But there is a problem when I run it for the entire dataset! I have nearly 10 million SNPs, when I run the script for the entire data-set it does not produce any output! I wonder what might be wrong....?

Comment: @Anna1364 Does it actually terminate without producing any output or does it just run for a really, really long time? I didn't put any effort into making it efficient. If your input is really large than it might take a long time or possibly hang or crash.

Comment: @Anna1364 If you post your data somewhere (e.g. GitHub or something) then I'll running the script on your data myself.

Comment: @Anna1364 I'd rather not post my email address. Can you put it somewhere public?

Comment: @igal, I do not have any GitHub page! Any other idea where can I share my data with you? Your code gives exactly what I want, just does not work with the entire data. Thanks for your help! –

Comment: @Anna1364 You can sign up for GitHub for free. Or you can share a public link from a cloud hosting server (e.g. Google Drive, DropBox, etc.).

Comment: If the files are very large, processing them in memory might take a long time and/or exhaust memory. In that case, you would probably be better off changing this solution into sqlite one, putting the rows into SQL db and running a query on them. For sql purposes, the structure seems very simple.

Comment: @Gnudiff I had the same initial thought as you, but we're being told that the program runs to completion without error. I would have expected it to hand or crash if it ran out of memory - don't you think?

Comment: @igal I was not completely certain of that. However, in case you are right, there probably are some rows that somehow reset the result?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid large waiting times, you could do this with the minimalistic SQL engine SQLite that is frequently preinstalled in Linux. It doesn't run a server, and works with SQL databases that are stored in files.

In your snp_data & window directory do:

```
cat snp_data | tr -s " " > snp_data.csv
sed 's#Chr##g' window | tr -s " " > window.csv
```

This normalizes the spaces between fields and prepares them for import.

Then import this data into SQL and run the query to get the output:

```
cat > task.sql
CREATE TABLE snp_data (snp_id text,chromosome int, position int);
CREATE TABLE window (seqname int,chromosome int, c_start int , c_end int, c_width int);

.mode csv
.separator "  "
.import snp_data.csv snp_data
.import window.csv window

.mode column
.header on
SELECT D.snp_id, D.chromosome, D.position, W.seqname FROM snp_data D, window W WHERE W.chromosome=D.chromosome AND D.position BETWEN W.c_start AND W.c_end;
```

[CTRL+D here to stop input]

And finally:

```
cat task.sql | sqlite3 my_database.db
```

In general, this should be faster for large files.